# Perfect Matchings in Biclique Decompositions of Multigraphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, multigraphs

suppose you have the $K_{2n}$ covered by a multigraph consisting of $2n-1$ bicliques, each consisting of a partition of the vertex set into two sets of equal size.

Here is a picture of $K_{6}$ with 5 bicliques.

[image]

My question is: under which circumstances is it possible to pick a perfect matching of each biclique, such that every edge of $K_{2n}$ is covered exactly once?

I know so far, that obviously every edge should be covered at least once and every vertex has $n$ edges of one color. Moreover a biclique can only occur at most $n-1$ ($n$ odd) or $n$ ($n$ even) times.

Is there any theory regarding this question?

Comment: Did you have a look at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/78385/decomposition-of-a-complete-graph-into-maximal-matching-subgraphs?rq=1
It might be related to your question. Look at the first comment to the answer of this question.

Comment: The question is quite related. Unfortunately it answers whether for $K_{2n}$ SOME coloring like that is possible (this is true). In my problem, the coloring is given.